# Leaving the sukkah when it rains, making a bracha upon returning

Tags: blessing, sukkah, meal-seudah

Someone had started eating in a sukkah (and made a "leishev") then after some time it started to rain. They moved into their house and waited then for the rain to stop. When the rain stopped they returned to their sukkah to continue eating. However not enough time had passed by where normally a new bracha would be made (for example according to the SA HaRav this is one or two hours.) Should a new "leishev" be made? Would it matter if they had continued eating the seudah in their house or was waiting for the rain to stop in order to continue eating in the sukkah?

(the sofek is if the rain casues a hesech hadas or if since the person doesn't have a sukkah that is "fitting" to eat in that this would somehow cause them to loose the original bracha. Perhaps there are more tzadidim to this as well which people can raise in the comments or hopefully address them in the answer.)

Comment: Similar: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/83788